# Mongodb groupby range of date and id

Tags: mongodb

I have a database

```
  {
    "_id": "222jMQDEHuHXTuDeF",
    "customer_id": "QfdAFubKS9ytdbhbq",
    "createdDate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-27T08:19:40.791Z"
    } 
  }, 
  {
    "_id": "278jKLDEHuHXItDeF",
    "customer_id": "HtdAFubJS8ytdnjbe",
    "createdDate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-26T08:19:40.791Z"
    } 
   }, 
   {
    "_id": "128lRLDEHuHXItPhy",
    "customer_id": "KodATubJS8yyqkjbe",
    "createdDate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-25T08:19:40.791Z"
    } 
   }
```

I need to get data of the previous week where current date is the end date and group by date and customer_id and get the count of customer_id in mongodb.

Comment: If you answer helps you please tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

You can compare like following. For the easiness I have added `previouseWeekStart`, but you can directly call it inside the `$match` stage instead of using `$addFields`. This should definitely work, but I can't show a demo in mongoplayground since I have added subtract symbol (`-`) for calculating previous date.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      previouseWeekStart: new Date(new Date()-7*60*60*24*1000)
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$createdDate",
              "$previouseWeekStart"
            ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              "$createdDate",
              new Date()
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        cusId: "$customer_id",
        date: "$createdDate"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```